# Rails button to generate UUID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uuid

I'm fairly new to both ruby and rails but I've managed to create a controller and view to create a new "organization" record in a rails application:

```
class OrganizationsController < ApplicationController
```

I also have the form to create a new organization and have included a button in the form to generate a UUID for the record:

```
 <button class="btn btn-small" type="button" title="Generate UUID">
 Generate UUID
 </button>
```

When pressed, I would like this button to generate a UUID put the UUID in an existing field within the same form:

```
 <div class="field">
 <%= f.label :uuid %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :uuid %>
 </div>
```

I figured out a way using JS but would rather use SecureRandom.UUID in a method within my controller class. How is this possible? Or is there a better place to put this method?

Edit:

Thanks, so now I have the following method:

```
 helper_method :generate_uuid
 def generate_uuid
    puts SecureRandom.uuid
 end
```

And the form has the following:

```
  <%= button_to "Generate UUID", :method=> "generate_uuid" %>


  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :uuid %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :uuid,  :value => generate_uuid %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
```

The button still won't generate and populate the field and in addition, the generate_uuid button submits the actual form while this method should only be allowed by the f.submit button. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Make your controller method a helper method by doing the following

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :generate_uuid

  def generate_uuid
  end
end
```

You can now use this method in your view

```
<div class="field">
 <%= f.label :uuid %><br>
 <%= f.text_field :uuid, "", :value => generate_uuid %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm one step closer. Please see my edits above.

Comment: make it a link instead of a button. I think you will have to make an ajax request when the link is clicked and populate the input field with the ajax response